# How do I store a reference to a file in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, xml, file-upload

I have a .xml file of a list of items in a bulk shipment. I need to be able to parse that .xml file and write that to an array, which will then be displayed on a table in the app.

The very general pseudo code I have planned is:

- Create a button that can accept a .xml file upload
- Store a reference to that file in a variable
- Call function to populate a new array with data in .xml
- Display that array in a table

I am stuck at the second step (temporarily storing that file somehow) but I wouldn't be surprised if I have to revise the first step.

Here is my code so far, which is essentially just a button that asks for a file upload in a popup

HTML:

```
<input type="file" id="file" style="display:none;" />  
<button id="button" name="button" value="Upload" onclick="importFileSelector();">ImportManifest</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
    var files = (function() { return document.getElementById("file").click().files; })(); 
}
```

I guess my question boils down to this: is there any way to store a reference to a file in JavaScript so that I can call relevant functions on that file?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. After you accept a file from your `input[type=file]` you can read the file contents using the [FileReader API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) and store it in a variable.

HTML:

```
<input type="file-input" id="file" accept="text/xml" />
```

JavaScript:

```
const fileInput = document.querySelector('#file-input');

const domParser = new DOMParser();

window.addEventListener('change', async () => {
   const file = fileInput.files[0];

   const xmlText = await readFileAsync(file);

   const xmlDoc = domParser.parseFromString(xmlText, "text/xml");

   // run commands over xmlDoc
});

async function readFileAsync(file) {
   const fileReader = new FileReader();

   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      fileReader.addEventListener('error', () => reject(fileReader.error));
      fileReader.addEventListener('load', () => {
         resolve(fileReader.result);
      });

      fileReader.readAsText(file, "UTF-8");
   });
}
```

This will read the file you've selected through your input and parse it to an XML DOM tree document which you can run queries against. You can check more about the [DOMParser here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser).